# Should I remove (seemingly unimportant) language tags to make room for important ones?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes I come across questions (mainly from low rep newbies) with many unimportant tags but missing the ones that are suitable for their question. In such cases I usually remove obviously irrelevant tags and add the right ones (from my perspective). Of course I do this only in fields I know about, and usually left a comment to the author to check if I did not accidentally break something ...

Today I came across this interesting question: [Color Suppression Formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33769111/2)

It was initially tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors), and later also with [rgba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rgba).

I would tag it as: [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) [scattering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scattering) [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) [physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics) [colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors) [rgba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rgba) instead, but there was no room left so I got rid of the [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) tag and prioritized [image-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) instead.

After my edits, this is the result: [White balance (Color Suppression) Formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33769111/2521214)

Now the question is, should I remove the language tags too, or else what to do in such cases?

This feels like a too big change (even if the language is nowhere mentioned in the question or even related to an answer ...) as I do not know the background of this problem from the OP's side. I would like to know the community opinion on this. For now I left an edit suggestion comment to the author instead.

I strongly feel those tags will attract **the right people** to the question so it may be answered in more detail or simply better.

**Note**

I searched for similar question here on Meta but I found only merging or renaming retags questions. So if it is a duplicate I did not find, I apologize (I'm not very active on Meta so it is hard for me to find something here without knowing the right phrases ...).

Comment: Removing the languages ".. as I do not know the background of this problem from the OP side" – remove them. It reads as if the OP is looking for a pure algorithm. If not, or alternatively, if the algorithm should be in a certain language, then he should mention this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question: language tags and general tags.

It's usually important to keep the language tag. In this case, however, it's not entirely clear why the question's tagged with both JS and Python.

If it is indeed an algorithm question, the author should have said something like "I know JS and Python, so I prefer answers that use either of these languages" (or not said anything, psudocode is fairly easy to read).

If it was specific to one language, it should have been clear that they were looking for solutions in that language. But it would be too broad to look for solutions for Python and solutions for JS. It's not like it had Python and Java tags, which would indicate a possible Jython tag.

This would allow people to suggest existing libraries with the functionality.

In this case, it would be good to ask the OP to clarify if they are looking for a specific language.

---

As for the generic (non-language) tags, I think you need to look at three things before you use the tag.

1. The tag wiki. For example, did you know that `bold` does not refer to **this bold**?

The `physics` tag isn't used to describe any and all of the physics field. It refers to physics engines, and, in general, focuses on how entities move.

2. Questions using the tag.

Looking at `light`, it seems it is usually used for questions that involve making something lighter, not anything involving photons.

3. How many people follow the tag?

Did you know that scattering isn't even a tag? [`Light-scattering`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light-scattering) has a total of 1 question and one follower, so it's not really going to bring in the masses.

Also, keep in mind that just because something is in the question, doesn't mean that it should be in the tags. Yes, the solution will involve math, but it doesn't really add any value. Most programming questions will involve some math, anyway. The tag should probably only be used if the question involves hardcore mathematical concepts that the general population wouldn't know.